# Adjusting UIdefaults

Tags: java, user-interface

I currently have:

http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/2702/48211978.png

How do I get the titledborder to this? http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/9818/27722148.png

I've been trying to figure this out for a week now and I'm still stuck... Does anyone know how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TitledBorder` but in the constructor pass a `LineBorder` or an `EtchedBorder`.

Comment: TitledBorder title = new TitledBorder("Client Downloader");
                Border color = new LineBorder(Color.white, 1);
                contentPanel.setBorder(title);
                contentPanel.setBorder(color);
                contentPanel.setLayout(null);

Comment: Maybe something like this: `setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE), "Client Downloader"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
LineBorder lb = new LineBorder(Color.white, 1);
TitledBorder tb = new TitledBorder (lb, "Client Downloader");
contentPanel.setBorder (tb);
```